# Collision event twice as3

Tags: actionscript-3, object, collision, hit

I have a brick clip that goes to frame 2 when hit by a ball clip. This code is inside the brick class, which is why why it is referred as "this":

```
if (this.hitTestObject(_root.mcBall)){
    _root.ballYSpeed *= -1;
    this.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

My question is when it is hit the second time how can it go to frame 3? What code do I need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify the current frame of your brick and then if it's **frame 2** go to **frame 3**, like this :

```
if (this.currentFrame === 2){     
    this.gotoAndStop(3)
}
```

You can also use a `boolean` to indicate if your brick has been hit. If `true`, go to frame 3.

EDIT

**AS code :**

**- Using a boolean :**

```
...

var hit:Boolean = false

...

if (this.hitTestObject(_root.mcBall)){
    _root.ballYSpeed *= -1
    if(!hit){        // this is the 1st time so set hit to true and go to frame 2
        hit = true
        this.gotoAndStop(2)
    } else {         // this is the 2nd time so go to frame 3
        this.gotoAndStop(3)
    }
}
```

**- Using currentFrame :**

```
if (this.hitTestObject(_root.mcBall)){  
    _root.ballYSpeed *= -1  
    if (this.currentFrame == 1){    // we are in the 1st frame so go to frame 2 
        this.gotoAndStop(2)
    } else {                        // we are certainly not in the 1st frame so go to frame 3
        this.gotoAndStop(3)
    }
}
```

I hope that is more clearer.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know booleans too well yet. Would you give me an example?

Comment: I tried:    if(this.hitTestObject(_root.mcBall)) &&
  if (this.currentFrame == 2);{     
                 this.gotoAndStop(3); And it would not work, Do you know if there is anything like that i can use?

Comment: Your code should be like this : ` if(this.hitTestObject(_root.mcBall) && this.currentFrame == 2){ this.gotoAndStop(3); } `. note that it was just a correction of your code.

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope that's more clearer now ;)

Comment: I think the approach could be better with `this.nextFrame()`

Answer (score 1):

Try a "clean" approach, like this:

```
if (this.hitTestObject(_root.mcBall)){
    _root.ballYSpeed *= -1;
    if (this.currentFrame !== 3) {
        this.nextFrame();
    }
}
```

This makes the clip go to its next frame if its current frame isn't 3.

Comment: Thank you! But I need to go to frame 3 when it is hit again, not automatically when it's on frame 2.

Comment: @Johnnien This goes to frame 2 the first time it's hit and frame 3 the second time... if you don't understand the code you could at least try it... I can't corrupt your system with this code, can I? ;) Anyway, it's basically saying "If the frame isn't 3, go to the next frame" every time it's hit.

Comment: I am sorry! i did not want to sound mean..... I did try it before i wrote you, and went straight to frame 3. Anyway.  Thank you!

Comment: @Johnnien Meh, I don't understand how your game works :( Anyway, it looks like your question was solved. Good luck on your game!